# Swift Realm - ATS failed system trust

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am upgrading a project from Swift 3 to Swift 5. The project uses Realm for an internal database, but every time I launch the app in the simulator I get the following errors in the console:

```
ATS failed system trust
Connection 2: system TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9802)
```

I'm pretty sure this is a Realm issue as the app doesn't try to make any other external connections. When running on a older version of Xcode(8), it all works fine without errors. I'm currently testing on Xcode 10.3 and 11 (beta) and using Realm 3.17.3.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

This error is only produced in the simulator. When running on an actual device no errors get logged

Comment: have you add NSAppTransportSecurity key in info.plist ?

Comment: No, but if it's an internal database, what url would i add?

Comment: I've been using Realm in Xcode 10 since 10.1 - I've also used it in Xcode 11 beta and GM. This issue doesn't exist for me.

Comment: Problem solved. This error is only produced in the simulator. When running on an actual device no errors get logged